# How to pass 2 consecutive arguments using POpen communicate()

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to execute a linux command through Python.
Here, for one of the command (cryptsetup luksChangeKey) I need to pass two keys [current key and new key] when prompted by the command through STDIN.
I tried using communicate() for the same and not able to pass both the keys.

Is there any other option available in python for the above scenario  ?

Sample Code:

```
import subprocess
cmd = 'cryptsetup --batch-mode --key-file - luksChangeKey 
      /dev/multiplelv_pool_VG_13341/lv4'
process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
process.stdin.write("old123\nnew123\n")
process.communicate()
process.stdin.close()
```

If we manually execute the cryptsetup command, then it will prompt for old key and then the new key to be provided.

I am trying to simulate the same through the Python code.

Here current password is old123 and new password is new123.

My expectation of using '\n' in stdin.write was to split the password into two lines. However, POpen is taking the entire
line as current password and resulting in error

I am using Python 2.7

Comment: post some code!!!

Comment: @PentaKill - have edited the question with sample code

Comment: I don't know `cryptsetup`, but in general you want to avoid passing data around via stdin like that.  it's normal for programs to read passwords directly from `/dev/tty` (rather than from standard input).  you're better off finding a library that exposes appropriate functionality, or, failing that, using command line parameters to tell it what to expect (i.e. actually pass a file name to `--key-file`)

Comment: My requirement is to pass data as strings and not store it in any file. 
So using --key-file is not possible.

Can I pass 2 individual strings using stdin to be provided as input to the command executed using POpen communicate ?

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

*other.py*

```
a = input()
b = input()
print(a, b)
```

*program.py*

```
import subprocess

cmd = r'python other.py'
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
process.communicate("input1\ninput2".encode('utf-8'))
process.stdin.close()

# print: >>> input1 input2
```

The [subprocess documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stderr) warns about the use of `stdin.write`.

Also, I don't know how your code doesn't throw an error, since you are passing a string to stdin and not a bytes-like object? This is what happens for me with your code:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: I would assume that OP is using a Python 2.x version.

Comment: Yeah, the question's flags are indeed confusing

Comment: Have edited the question. I am using python 2.7
Above solution does not work for me when I use cryptsetup command

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Python problem but a `cryptsetup` limitation. It is explicit in the manpage (emphasize mine):

> ```
> --key-file, -d<br/>
>      use file as key material.
> ```
>
> ... If the key file is "-", stdin will be used. **With the "-" key file reading will not stop when new line character is detected**.

and later:

> Notes on Password Processing
>   ...
>   From stdin: Reading will continue until EOF

Workarounds:

According to [this post on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/1347340), it used to be possible to pass both the old and new passwords in the same keyfile, but it would no longer be possible. A trick would be to use stdin for the old key, and stdout for the new one. Python will refuse to write on a `process.stdout` file because it is only opened for reading, but it is still possible to write on it at the fileno level. Code would become:

```
import subprocess
cmd = 'cryptsetup --batch-mode --key-file - luksChangeKey 
      /dev/multiplelv_pool_VG_13341/lv4 /dev/fd/1'         # read the new key from /dev/fd/1
process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
os.write(process.stdout.fileno(), 'new123')
process.communicate('old123')
```

Beware: untested because I currently have no Linux system with LUKS.

Comment: Thank you Serge for the reply.
os.write() fails with bad descriptor error. file descriptor is kind of closed before os.write() call happens.

Comment: I am sorry but I have no available Linux system to do more tests. Maybe the post from SuperUser could give you a possible way?

Answer (score 0):

A way to trick cryptsetup would be to use the `pexpect`-module (needs to be installed separately). This runs a subprocess faking a controlling terminal. It then allows to wait for prompts and issue user input when prompted. This is e.g. a way to control SSH and enter a password instead of having to resort to public keys etc.

Comment: Yup. Have tried this and it works. 
I was more interested in knowing if we can tweak something and have it working with subprocess module.